# Write elements to textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to get a text from a  and add some attributes to the text and show it in another  when a button is pressed.

Here is a part of my code - If I use console.log() the correct text will be logged, but the append(x) only writes the option[i] value without any HTML codes.

What should be the solution here?

```js
var options;
$(function() {
  options = $('div#Thelper2_container textarea').val().split('\n');
  $.fillTextArea();

});

$.fillTextArea = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var y = i + 1;
    var x = String('<span class="textToSelect" value="' + y + '"></span>' + options[i] + '</span>\n');
    $('div#Thelper4_container textarea').append(x);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Thelper2_container">
  <textarea rows="5" cols="100">Line 1
Line 2
</textarea>
</div>
<div id="Thelper4_container">
  <textarea rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: use val instead of append

Comment: in this way the previous values will be overwritten, so only the text of the last iteration will be in the textarea

Comment: See my [UPDATED answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561491/295783) to see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div#Thelper4_container textarea').append(document.createTextNode(x));
```

Please note the 'document.createTextNode'.

Comment: This is such a inefficient solution. You basically append html you convert to text before appending. Also it does not remove empty lines

Comment: Yep, the String() before is useless. My solution maybe is not elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Use val instead of append. Append is for non-form field container elements

Although you CAN append to a textarea, when you append, you append HTML and not text.

Also you have too many `</span>`s and spans do not have values. I changed to  data-value

Lastly I filter empty lines

```js
const $txtarea = $('#Thelper2_container textarea');
const $output =  $('#Thelper4_container textarea');
const splitLines = val => val
  .split('\n')
  .filter(line => line.trim() !== "") // drop empty lines
  .map((line,i) => `<span class="textToSelect" data-value="${i+1}">${line.trim()}</span>`)
  .join("\n");

$(function() {
  $output.val(splitLines($txtarea.val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Thelper2_container">
  <textarea rows="5" cols="100">Line 1
Line 2
</textarea>
</div>
<div id="Thelper4_container">
  <textarea rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending another `</span>\n` at the end of the string without opening it anywhere.

Try this code and see if it works:

```
var x = String('<span class="textToSelect" value="' + y + '"></span>' + options[i] + '\n');
```